# Programmatically hilight map areas when mouse over with ng-maphilight

Tags: angular, module, maphilight

I am using the module `ng-maphilight` in my Angular 8 project.

I have multiple areas that I want to hilight when one area is hovered.

Is it possible to hilight map areas when mouse over programmatically using this module?

[ng-maphilight on Github](https://github.com/TylerRick/ng-maphilight)